# Showing step by step solving of sudoku

Tags: python, processing, sudoku

Is there any way to show the steps of solving a sudoku? My code just solve it within 0.5 second and I wish to modify it to show the changes on the sudoku grid step by step on processing. (I am using python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all steps of solving sudoku (e.g. Grid data) into a list. For each step you modify the sudoku state, you clone a copy and append it to the global list. After solved it, you can loop through this list and render each state with some seconds delay.